# Troubles retrieving data from within OnRowCommand from a GridViews

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dynamic-data

If I have this `<asp:ButtonField runat="server" DataTextField="Name" CommandName="GetName"></asp:ButonField>` Within a GridView. Is there any way to retrieve the DataTextField (Name) from the OnRowCommand method?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
 AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
 DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource_Names" 
 DataKeyNames="ID,ModuleId" OnRowCommand="ChangeName">
```

Or alternatively, is there any way to make CommandName into an attribute where the command is dynamically entered based on given data, similar to the difference between DataTextField vs TextField.

Answer (score 0):

I added `<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" />` Then you can retrieve it using the same method here: [GridView.onRowCommand Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.onrowcommand.aspx)

All I need to do now is find out a way to hide the field. If anyone knows how to, please let me know. Visible="false" gets rid of the field all together...

Comment: In your BoundField add  ControlStyle-CssClass="someClass". Put someClass in your page or style sheet and set its display: none;.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure if this is the best way, but it works:

Make your column a templatefield and bind the name value to a asp:hiddenfield control:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
   <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:HiddenField ID="hfName" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("Name") %>'>
      </asp:HiddenField>
   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```